# Obnoxious squealing when starting truck and when accelerating from a stop

Tags: noise, timing, serpentine-belt, tensioner

My 2000 Mitsubishi Montero Sport LS 4x4 has been making a nasty squeal when starting it and when I accelerate from a stop. I'm not sure exactly what is causing it. The water pump, timing belt, and serpentine belts were just replaced.

Comment: Why not check the fan belt and tighten if necessary

Comment: As Autistic wrote - always suspect the last thing touched.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!